Can I ask a company for money in exchange for info on a bug
Suppose one found information about a large organisations software, for example Apple Pay, about their payment system that could cause very bad legal trouble for them. This could be related to to the fact that all purchases must be tracked. But with what’s going on they aren’t.
Is there a way to offer the information in exchange for money without risking breaking the law?  In particular one should avoid the risk of anything that could be interpreted as a threat.
The potential for legal consequences is indicated by cases such as the reporter in Missouri who was threatened but not prosecuted with legal action in relation to "unlawful to access encoded data and systems in order to examine other people's personal information" aka pressing f12 in a browser and 18 year old Hungarian who was arrested for much the same.  Note neither of these requested payment.

Some companies voluntarily participate in "bug bounty" programs. But demanding money walks a very thin line to blackmail.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45918, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50749, and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/25286; and probable duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38517

@feetwet It is surprising how many contradictory answers to a seemingly simple and real world question there are.

@MichaelHall, depends on the service and the exact words. The proverbial "nice shop you, have, it would be a pity if anything happened to it" is different from genuine fire insurance.

@MichaelHall it all depends on the wording of the demand. "I found this bug, what do you pay to get the details?" is quite different from "I found this bug. It would be a pitty if I did not get 200 bitcoin from you and had to sell the exploit on the black market."

@Trish yeah! I don’t wanna ransom or blackmail them or anything. I just wanna ask if they would be willing to pay for it.

@Melina They don't know that. Even if you have no such plans, they may report you to the police for trying to extort them, and you'll have to defend yourself.

Trish & o.m. I am quite clear on the difference between an offer to help vs a threat, but thanks...  Anyway, this is less a question about law, and more a question about how to draft a proposal that will be received favorably.

Large tech and software firms do solicit feedback on casual bugs and pay bounties to people who credibly identify security issues and offer some legal cover through the process.
For example, Apple describes its bounty program at https://security.apple.com/bounty/:

If you believe you’ve discovered a security or privacy vulnerability
that affects Apple devices, software, or services, please report it
directly to us. We review all eligible research for Apple Security
Bounty rewards.

The report submission process will ask for an Apple ID for tracking purposes and details of the research you have done to confirm the vulnerability. (It's always possible someone else already pointed out the issue and it's being evaluated, but not yet resolved.)
There are also a number of terms and conditions, including not disclosing the nature of the vulnerability to anyone else pending a resolution of the case, as well as not violating any applicable laws. The process should otherwise immunize you from legal action from the corporation.

It should be noted that this process puts all the negotiation power into the hands of the tech/ software firm. You report the bug, sign that you are not abusing it or showing it to anyone else and then they decide whether they will pay you anything for it or not.

On the other hand, avoiding payment for something that is genuinely helpful doesn’t make much business sense.
